# How to format HTTP API call in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, etherpad

I am currently following the [etherpad documentation](https://github.com/ether/etherpad-lite/wiki/HTTP-API) in regards to calling the HTTP API "*getText*"

How would the API call be structured given these parameters?

```
Pad content can be updated and retrieved through the API

getText(padID, [rev]) returns the text of a pad 

Example returns:

{code: 0, message:"ok", data: {text:"Welcome Text"}}
{code: 1, message:"padID does not exist", data: null}
```

Answer (score 1):

You'll need 2 parameters:

1. apiKey
2. padID

The apiKey can be retrieved from a text file named `APIKEY.txt` in the root of etherpad-lite.

The padID is in the format `groupID$padID`.

Putting it all together, you can query the pad's content using the following endpoint and payload:

`http://pad.domain.com/api/1/getText?apikey=<apiKey>&padID=<padID>`

Ex: `http://pad.domain.com/api/1/getText?apikey=6b2d257663asddfe8c78f33f94d8e7290asdasd1dea820ea0c37cf42602ea5eef3c&padID=g.fcXsYTpiNlJMwX35$samplePad`